# the same jquery ajax request is being sent several times

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have dynamically created table. There is an "update" link on each row of that table. When I click on that link, everything works okay, but I see in console network (F12) that it generates multiple ajax requests instead of one (the same request is being sent several times). Could you please check the code below and help me to solve the problem.

```
$('#load_table').click(function() {
    $.get('cont/get_table', function (data) {

        var item = $('<table>');

        $.each(data.results, function (i, res) {

            var row = $('<tr>').append(
            $('<td class="a">').html(res.id),
            $('<td class="b" contenteditable="true">').html(res.title),
            $('<td class="c" contenteditable="true">').html(res.text),
            $('<td>').html('<a href="#" class="update">Update</a>'));
            item.append(row);
        });

        $("#display").html(item);

        $("body").on("click", ".update", function () {

            var row = $(this).closest('tr'); 
            var id = row.find('td.a').text();
            var title = row.find('td.b').text();
            var text = row.find('td.c').text();

            $.post('cont/update_row', {
                id: id,
                title: title,
                text: text
            }, function (data) {

                //display data
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basic error: You have several elements with id ="update". Change it to class.

```
    $.each(data.results, function (i, res) {

    var row = $('<tr>').append(
    $('<td class="a">').html(res.id),
    $('<td class="b" contenteditable="true">').html(res.title),
    $('<td class="c" contenteditable="true">').html(res.text),
    $('<td>').html('<a href="#" class="update">Update</a>'));
    item.append(row);

    row.on('click', '.update',function(){
    $.post('cont/update_row', {
        id: res.id,
        title: res.title,
        text: res.text
    }, function (data) {

        //display data
    });
});


$("#display").html(item);
```

Second approach - move that function outside of your ajax call, baceuse with each call aou are adding another event to your update button.

```
$("body").on("click", ".update", function () {
        var row = $(this).closest('tr'); 
        var id = row.find('td.a').text();
        var title =  row.find('td.b').text();
        var text =  row.find('td.c').text();

        $.post('cont/update_row', {
            id: id,
            title: title,
            text: text
        }, function (data) {

            //display data
        });
    });
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. Actually, it was not working with 'class' and I changed 'class' to 'id'. Now I changed it back to 'class' but the problem still exists. Could you please check.

Comment: Found your bug-I think. Move your body.on('click') function outside your ajax call. Everytime you make that call you add another event to every update buttons.

Answer (score 2):

You create multiple `<a>` links with the same `id='update'`, which is incorrect and might generate this bug. Try changing to `class='update'`.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Actually, it was not working with 'class' and I changed 'class' to 'id'. Now I changed it back to 'class' but the problem still exists. Could you please check.